# How can I extract a word from a string using Oracle regexp_substr?

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

I'm trying to extract a word from a string using Oracle 12c regexp_substr but no luck in understanding how it works, too much info in the net and I get confused.

So I want to extract `tmp*` tables from a string:

`query_str`:

```
 select 
 column1 c1,
 column2 c2
 from tmp_123 foo1, -- some comments here
 TAB1_123 TAB1
 where 1=1
;
```

Trying to use this but no "luck":

```sql
select regexp_substr(query_str, 'TMP_[A-z]+', 1, 1, 'i');
```

I want to extract until the space and the tmp table name can have numbers in the middle like this: `tmp_123`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe `'TMP_\w+'` or `'TMP_\S+'`?

Comment: I think it works amazing thanks

Comment: whats the difference between W (word) and S (space)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of the two:

```sql
select regexp_substr(query_str, 'TMP_\w+', 1, 1, 'i');
select regexp_substr(query_str, 'TMP_\S+', 1, 1, 'i');
```

The `\w+` will match alphanumeric or underscore chars after `TMP_` and `\S+` will match one or more non-whitespace chars.

See the [`\w` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBH5Tt/1) and the [`\S` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBH5Tt/2).

Comment: thanks and I cannot upvote because of my reputation?!?!

Comment: @mendesn Now you can. Please also consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: The former probably better than the latter, since in a `from` clause a table name is often immediately followed by a comma (if there's no alias for the table). Also, this will match `TMP_whatever` from `NEW_TMP_whatever`; worth asking the OP if that must be handled.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that the SELECT statement shown is not valid in Oracle, where a FROM clause is required. Here's an example of how to make this work:

```
WITH cteData
  AS (SELECT 'select' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'column1 c1,' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'column2 c2' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'from tmp_123 foo1, -- some comments here' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'TAB1_123 TAB1' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'where 1=1' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT ';' AS QUERY_STR FROM DUAL)
select regexp_substr(query_str, 'TMP_[A-z]+', 1, 1, 'i') AS MATCH
  FROM cteData
  WHERE regexp_substr(query_str, 'TMP_[A-z]+', 1, 1, 'i') IS NOT NULL
```

Here I've put your data line-for-line into a Common Table Expression (CTE) named "cteData" which the SELECT then uses as the source of its data. This returns the line

```
tmp_123 foo1, -- some comments here
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f069b211c6eb7b6188f4a0c05c1c61ed)